# Cassandra: concurrent snapshot and clear snapshot?

Tags: cassandra, cron

I have a daily cron job[1] which take snapshots of cassandra, and upload it to s3 buckets. After doing that, the snapshots will be deleted.

However, there is also a pipeline job that takes snapshot of cassandra, *which I cannot modify*. This job does not delete snapshots after it's done and it relies on another daily cron job[2] to delete all snapshots (basically call `nodetool clearsnapshot`).

My concern now is that, the daily cron job[2] might delete my snapshots, and thus my cron job[1] will not be able to upload them into s3 buckets. What will happen if my `nodetool snapshot` and `nodetool clearsnapshot` of another job happens at the same time? Is there a way to require the daily cron job[2] to happen after my cron job[1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodetool snapshot` has the functionality to tag the snapshots. One way to solve this is to compromise with the owner of the other process so every time that a snapshot is taken, it is properly tagged.

Your backup procedure should be something similar to:

```
nodetool snapshot -t backup
... upload to s3 ...
nodetool clearsnapshot -t backup
```

The other pipeline can have its own tag:

```
nodetool snapshot -t pipeline
```

And the crontab should include the pipeline's tag

```
nodetool clearsnapshot -t pipeline
```

If there is no chance to change the pipeline to include the tag, you may restrict the execution of the cron job so it will verify that no backup process is running (like looking for a PID) before doing the `clearsnapshot`.

Comment: Thanks! The tag approach seems to be very clean! I'll try that first. Thanks again for pointing this out!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you